# How to solve W/OkHttpClient: A connection was leaked?

Tags: java, https

I'm trying to create a connection to some remote server, and get the following warning in my LogCat: `"W/OkHttpClient: A connection to "some url" was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?"`
Now I don't understand why is it happening. 
I use Apache IO commons to count number of bytes sent and received, and it's the only use if mine with OkHTTP.
Can you please look at my code snippet and tell me what's wrong with it?

This is the code where I try to create a connection:

```
public static JSONObject getConfiguration(Context context) throws HttpRequestException {

        long bytes = 0;
        long netUsage = HttpUtils.getCurrentNetworkUsage(context);

        int statusCode = 0, count = 0;
        NetworkRequest.Status netStatus = NetworkRequest.Status.FAILED;

        JSONObject commonInformation;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        CountingInputStream cis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        CountingOutputStream cos = null;
        // result
        JSONObject receivedConfig = null;

        try {

            commonInformation = ConfigurationProcessor.getCommonInformation(context);
            if (commonInformation == null) {
                return null;
            }

            URL url = new URL(BuildConfig.SERVER_CONFIG_URL);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                LogUtils.d(TAG, "url = " + url.getPath());
            }

            connection = url.getProtocol().equals("https")? getHttpsConnection(url) : getHttpConnection(url);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

            byte[] gzipped = HttpUtils.gzip(commonInformation.toString());
            cos = new CountingOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            cos.write(gzipped);
            cos.flush();

            statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            switch (statusCode) {

                case 200: {
                    // get the response
                    is = connection.getInputStream();
                    cis = new CountingInputStream(is);
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(cis);
                    br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String output;
                    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(output);
                    }

                    receivedConfig = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

                    netStatus = NetworkRequest.Status.SUCCEEDED;
                    break;
                }
                case 502: {
                    throw new HttpRequestException("Received 502 error (Bad Gateway)", NetworkRequest.Type.GET_REMOTE_CONFIGURATION);
                }
            }

            // analytics about the request
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                LogUtils.d(TAG, "generating analytics about the http request");
            }
            count = receivedConfig == null ? 0 : 1;

            if (cis != null) {
                bytes = cis.getByteCount();
            }

            if (cos != null) {
                bytes += cos.getByteCount();
            }

        } catch (Exception | OutOfMemoryError ex) {
            LogUtils.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            closeStream(is);
            closeStream(br);
            closeStream(isr);
            closeStream(cis);
            closeStream(cos);
            if (connection != null) connection.disconnect();
            createNetworkRequest(context, statusCode, netUsage, netStatus, count, bytes, NetworkRequest.Type.GET_REMOTE_CONFIGURATION, BuildConfig.SERVER_CONFIG_URL);
        }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.d(TAG, "Received configuration data");
        }
        return receivedConfig;
    }
```

Comment: Did you sorted out the error?

Comment: There were two things that I did which make the error go away. First, I updated the commons-io library to version 2.6 (I was uaing 2.4). Second thing was to call connection.getInputStream().close(), after I got the response from the server. I hope this helps.

Comment: ok but in my case there is no data coming from that API so I am only fetching the responsecode() from that connection.